# Mix create and update validations in single custom validator using ActiveModel::Validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

I found two alternatives to make use of the `ActiveModel::Validator` helper, but I am failing to find an easier or clean(er) approach than either checking for the presence of `record.id` or creating multiple custom validators.

I have a `User` class as follows:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_with UserValidator

  ...
end
```

and a custom validator

```rb
class UserValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    # validate some stuff
  end
end
```

The logic inside the `validate` method is executed no matter the action from the controller. So on `create` or on `update` (or `save`).

My goal is to split the logic and I have found multiple approaches that work but I don't really like either of them.

#### Approach 1: Check if a `record.id` exists

```rb
class UserValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.id.nil?
      # `on: :create` validations
    else
      # `on: :update` validations
    end
  end
end
```

#### Approach 2: Create multiple validator classes

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_with UserCreateValidator, on: :create
  validates_with UserUpdateValidator, on: :update

  ...
end
```

Preferably I would only have a single class `UserValidator` and within that custom validator check for some attribute or pass an option that would allow me to distinguish between `create` or `update`. Is that somehow achievable?

Comment: How about `!record.persisted?` instead of `record.id.nil?`?

Comment: @kcdragon you mean `record.new_record?`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class UserValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    if record.new_record?
      # `on: :create` validations
    else
      # `on: :update` validations
    end
  end
end
```

See [`ActiveRecord::Persistence`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.0.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html).